# Select an expression by CDbCriteria in Yii

Tags: mysql, yii

firstly, I using the codes below:

```
$c = new CDbCriteria();

$c->select = '*, DATEDIFF(deadline_time, NOW()) AS day_left';
$c->addCondition('DATEDIFF(deadline_time, NOW()) > 0');
$c->addCondition('DATEDIFF(deadline_time, NOW()) < :diff');
$c->params += array(':diff' => $diff);

$assigns = UserAssign::model()->findAll($c);
```

the query works fine, but I want to add some new condition through relations, so the codes turned to like this:

```
$c = new CDbCriteria();
$c->with = array('user');

if(Yii::app()->user->model->isAreaAdministrator) {
    $c->addCondition('user.city_id = :cityId');
    $c->params += array(':cityId' => Yii::app()->user->model->adminCityId);
}

$c->select = '*, DATEDIFF(deadline_time, NOW()) AS day_left';
$c->addCondition('DATEDIFF(deadline_time, NOW()) > 0');
$c->addCondition('DATEDIFF(deadline_time, NOW()) < :diff');
$c->params += array(':diff' => $diff);

$assigns = UserAssign::model()->findAll($c);
```

After I add the `with` property, the query seems not working, it dump the message `trying
to select an invalid column "DATEDIFF(deadline_time"` error.

I'm newbie to Yii, could anyone help me? 
Thanks.

Comment: tried that before, it will throw `NOW()) as day_left is invalid column` ...

Comment: does user table has column named deadline ?

Comment: Can you [configure](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging) a `CWebLogRoute`, set `YII_DEBUG` to `true` and paste the full SQL from the log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `DATEDIFF(deadline_time, NOW())` in the conditions with

```
new CDbExpression('DATEDIFF(deadline_time, NOW())')
```

I'm not sure it works in the `select` though. In case it doesn't you can use the `afterFind` function to set a public variable `$day_left` to the value of the `DATEDIFF(deadline_time, NOW())'`

```
class UserAssign{
    public $day_left;//new variable
    ...

    public function afterFind(){
        $this->day_left=date_diff(date_create($this->deadline_time),date_create('now'))->format('%R%a days');
        return parent::afterFind();
    }
}
```

Comment: cannot using `afterFind` event cuz I need using `day_left` column in `where` and `order` expressions, but thanks you very much !